# Why car tail lights look red?

Tags: optics, visible-light, wavelength

The car's tail light is made from red plastic material, and when the bulb from the inside switches on we see red colour, why? Is it just that the bulbs light illuminates that red plastic or wavelength changes what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red plastic absorbs all visible light far from red — namely green, blue etc.. What is left non-absorbed, goes through into your eyes, and you sense this light as red.

Comment: Exactly. And this is not limited to car headlights but anything. If you look at an object what you see is the reflected/transmitted (depending on circumstances)  part of the spectrum. No change of wavelength involved.

Comment: How it gets absorbed?And see if the plastic absorbs green wavelength, so it's electron would get excited and when they fall back, wouldn't they spit all that energy back??

Comment: @SarthakSharma After electron is excited, it has multiple ways of releasing this energy: emitting the same-frequency photon (reflection/scattering), emitting smaller-frequency photons (fluorescence), emitting phonons (heating), ... Not all of these ways will lead to you getting photon of that color back. The case of red plastic is normally heating, i.e. excited electron emits phonons, not photons.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks a lot for replying but isn't this process probabilistic, see is plastic designed in such a way That energy released after electron fall is 80-90% released as phonon or scattering , but we still see the colour as pure red, no green no yellow nothing else, isnt this possible in an ideal cases only??

Comment: @SarthakSharma indeed, red plastic doesn't only transmit "pure red" color. The [visible color spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum) is a continuous set of frequencies, and transmission curves of materials usually don't have sharp cut-offs. But even though there's some yellow light passing through, it has smaller intensity than red, and the final color thus becomes a bit orangish instead of pure red.